# Difference between $\mathbb{R}^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

We write $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be the set $\{(x_1,\dots,x_n): x_i \in \mathbb{R} \mbox{ for } i=1,\dots,n\}$, so $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples of real numbers. Is then $\mathbb{R}^1$ a set of 1-tuples but still "somehow the same" as $\mathbb{R}$? Is there any subtle difference between the two?

Comment: Usually $\Bbb R$ is meant to denote the field of real numbers, while $\Bbb R^1$ is meant to denote the one dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$. This could be a subtle difference. In this sense, there is *a priori* no "product" of two elements of $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: They aren't the same but since there's a very obvious identification between the sets that respects essentially all properties of the sets respectively, we often treat them as the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a $1$-tuple $(x)$ is the same thing (set-theoretically) as $x$. So even formally, no distinction exists.

Comment: @AlohaSine That depends entirely on how you set theoretically build your tuples. With the construction I'm used to they aren't the same.

Comment: This discussion parallels the discussion of whether integers are rational numbers, and whether rational numbers are real numbers.

Comment: If puns are still permitted here: $\mathbb R^1$ being an enforcement of $\mathbb R$, I suggest to spell it "$\mathbb R$ force $1$"

Comment: Like all mathematicians I'll ask "what does 'same' mean?"... I'm more inclined to think like AlohaSine that they are the same because there is a natural and obvious equivalence between them even if we interpret them as different types of objects. But I can see Don Thousand and Arthurs point.  ... If things are *equivalent* is there any point in noting differences in construction?  Is the integer $5$ we use to count five apples, the same or different than the $5$ we use to measure geometric distance?

Comment: @Arthur Out of curiosity, what construction of $n$-tuples are you used to? For me, I have seen them defined like this: the $1$-tuple $(x)$ is equal to the set $x$; the $2$-tuple $(x,y)$ is equal to the set $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$; and the $n$-tuple $(x,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n)$ is equal to the $2$-tuple $(y,x_n)$, where $y=(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ (defined inductively).

Comment: @Jason Tuples are in my book (Set Theory, 1st ed. by Kunen) defined as a set of ordered pairs, each pair containing an element and a number (von Neumann ordinal). So the triple $(x,y,z)$ is defined as $\{(x,0),(y,1),(z,2)\}$, where here the ordered pairs are defined the way you defined them. At least that's how I remember the definition. At the very least, one can use this to acknowledge that there are several ways to do it, and not all of them have $(x)=\{x\}$ or $(x)=x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: I decided to edit my answer to make it more explicit.

To straight up answer the question: is there a difference between ${\mathbb{R}}$ and ${\mathbb{R}^1}$? Yes, technically there is a difference.

When we speak about ${\mathbb{R}^n}$, we are talking about a vector space of dimension $n$ made of ${n}$-tuples over the complete ordered field ${\mathbb{R}}$. If you plug in ${n=1}$, you end up with a $1$-dimensional vector space made of $1$-tuples over ${\mathbb{R}}$.

You mentioned in the comments "*isn't ${\mathbb{R}}$ a vector space over ${\mathbb{R}}$?*" - you have to be careful with what you mean by this. The notation ${\mathbb{R}}$ is just referencing a complete ordered field, the notation ${\mathbb{R}^1}$ is when we are building a vector space out of ${\mathbb{R}}$ over itself, and we call it ${\mathbb{R}^1}$. There are structural differences between ${\mathbb{R}^1}$ and ${\mathbb{R}}$. We have no order defined on ${\mathbb{R}^1}$ by default, and also no multiplication defined. Well, we have the dot product, but this doesn't take us from ${\mathbb{R}^1\times \mathbb{R}^1\to \mathbb{R}^1}$, it takes us from ${\mathbb{R}^1\times \mathbb{R}^1\to \mathbb{R}}$:
$$
(x)\cdot (y) = xy \in \mathbb{R}
$$
so we need to first fix this:
$$
(x)\times (y) := (xy) \in \mathbb{R}^1
$$
and now we need to define an order, since by default ${\mathbb{R}^n}$ has no usual "order" attached to it. Define
$$
(x) < (y) \Leftrightarrow x < y
$$
and now if we define the map
$$
\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^1
$$
by
$$
\phi(x) = (x) \in \mathbb{R}^1
$$
it's an easy exercise now to verify that ${\phi}$ is an isomorphism with respect  to addition, our fixed multiplication, and the defined order. So now for our "fixed" ${\mathbb{R}^1}$, ${\mathbb{R}^1\cong \mathbb{R}}$.

In many texts, however, you will see ${\mathbb{R}^1}$ and ${\mathbb{R}}$ mostly considered as the same thing. Implicitly in the background, the fixing of multiplication and creation of an order is done, but we don't ever explicitly do it since it's rather trivial to do. Ultimately, it's just a matter of semantics when it comes to looking at the difference between ${\mathbb{R}^1}$ and ${\mathbb{R}}$.

Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: Thank you @Rieamann'sPointyNose for your detailed response! However, I am still puzzled. Isn't $\mathbb{R}$ itself also a vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$)? There we already have multiplication and order defined.

Comment: My question here is why do we need to consider $\mathbb{R}^1$ as a different vector space from $\mathbb{R}$? What are the elements of $\mathbb{R}^1$ exactly?

Comment: @MathCurious I have edited my answer. I hope that helps clear confusion. Note that ${\mathbb{R}}$ is not referencing a vector space, it's referencing a complete ordered field - ${\mathbb{R}^1}$ is referencing "taking the complete ordered field and building a vector space out of it over itself" - it's a very pedantic difference, but it is technically a difference

Answer (score 8):

Here is a somewhat different perspective.

It is quite common when we talk about $\mathbb{R}$ to think of the complete ordered field of $\left(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,<\right)$. But we also have to  consider the *context* in which the symbol $\mathbb{R}$ is used and this can make a big difference.

> Here are some examples of text blocks we can sometimes read:
>
> - (1) Let's consider the $\color{blue}{\text{additive group}}$ of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ ...
> - (2) Let's consider the $\color{blue}{\text{topological vector space}}$ $\mathbb{R}$ together with the usual euclidean topology ...
> - (3) Let's consider the $\color{blue}{\text{ring}}$ $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$ of real numbers where we use the usual addition and multiplication of real numbers ...
> - (4) Let's consider the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ ...
> - (5) Let's consider $\color{blue}{\text{the set}}$ of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

In the first three examples we have *additionally* to the set $\mathbb{R}$ also some kind of mathematical structure given. Each of these three examples provides us with some algebraic, or topological, or whatsoever mathematical *context* in which the set $\mathbb{R}$ should be considered.

Usually we do not have any problems to immediately switch into the right context (given we are already familiar with it). We then consider the real numbers precisely within this specific and restricted *environment*.

The example (4) is somewhat special, since here we do not have any additional context given. In this case it is common to consider $\mathbb{R}$ as complete ordered field $\left(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,<\right)$ and often this is the correct view.

> The example (5) is *different* to (4) since it explicitly puts the focus on the *plain* set structure of the real numbers: Let's consider *the set* of real numbers ... In this case the indicated context is rather the plain set structure and nothing else.
>
> We have to keep in mind that a set *per se* is just a set *without* any additional mathematical structures.

When looking at OP's question, the OP is addressing explicitly the *set structure* of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^1$.

So, what is the difference when restricting (naively, without formal considerations) on set structures? Let's exemplarily consider a finite set $X=\{a,b,c\}$. We have for $n\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
X^n=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)|x_j\in X, 1\leq j\leq n\}
\end{align*}
and as special case $n=1$ we have
\begin{align*}
X^1=\{(a),(b),(c)\}
\end{align*}
clearly showing that $X^1$ and $X$ are the same set with only some minor notational differences.

**Conclusion:** Considering the *set-structure* of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^1$ the difference is solely notational.