# Difference between a vector in $\Bbb{R^1}$ and a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

Many people say that they are the same, even I can't find much difference in them except that a vector/ matrix can be multiplied by any scalar, but to multiply it with a vector in $\Bbb{R^1}$ the vector or matrix should be of the order $1\times n$. What's and why is there a difference in this case?

Comment: I think you may be confusing the restrictions on dimensions for matrix multiplication with those for addition, for multiplication only the "inner" dimensions need to match.

Comment: yes, i understand that only the 'inner dimensions' need to match, if any vector in R1 were a scalar it wouldn't have been necessary  for the inner dimensions to match, but it is not the case

Comment: One context where the distinction can be important is when a $1 \times 1$ matrix appears as a factor in a matrix product. For example, if $x$ is a $n \times 1$ column vector, then $x^T x$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, so the product $(x^T x) x^T = x^T x x^T$ makes sense. If we did not maintain the distinction that $x^T x$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix as opposed to a scalar, we might be tempted to slide the "scalar" to the other side of the product (after all, you can do this with actual scalars) to obtain $x^T (x^T x) = x^T x^T x$. But this no longer makes sense: $x^T x^T$ is illegal.

Comment: This is similar to [Is $\mathbb{R}^1$ really the same as $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4124752/26369)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to formal definitions, the main difference is that:

- When you consider $\mathbb R$ as a field, the multiplication is an internal operation. That is maps an ordered pair $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ to $z= x \cdot y \in \mathbb R$.
- When you consider $V = \mathbb R$ as a one-dimensional vector space, then the multiplication is formally a [scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication) defined between two distinct objects: the field $\mathbb R$ and $V$.